# Dereferencing C++ STL list iterator

Tags: c++, list, stl, dereference

I'm looping through two STL lists (L1, L2) like so:

```
list<int>::const_iterator itr1 = L1.begin();
list<int>::const_iterator itr2 = L2.begin();

for (itr1; itr1 != L1.end(); itr1++) {
   if (*itr1 < *itr2) {
     //some code
   }

}
```

It compiles fine but when I run it, it says "Expression: list iterator not dereferencable"

Now in class we made a mock version of the STL list where we wrote our own STL list and we had overloaded the *operator to dereference an iterator. However, obviously it's not working here.

How can I dereference an iterator, or if STL list does it differently, how does it do it. I looked through this:

http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/List.html

documentation and didn't seem to find anything accept the member "reference" but still did not see how to reference what an iterator is pointing to, unless it's the first or last part of the list.

Anyone know what's going on here? Thank you

here is a pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/YRddqjmN

Comment: I made my best guess at the answer but when I compile the code above it works just fine. You may need to add OS and compiler details.

Comment: Good places to post some complete code to show the problem are http://pastebin.com and http://codepad.org

Comment: For example, I made a program from this and put it on codepad here: http://codepad.org/JgMBNAiW

Comment: I put a pastebin into the original post. And thanks again for your help guys.

Comment: The pasted code does not compile, but with the necessary trivial fixes, it works fine:  http://ideone.com/EbeVt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while ( *itr2 < *itr1 ) {
    itr2++;
}
```

That code has no check for running off the end of L2. Maybe add a check for `itr2 != L2.end()` to that.

Comment: you're right i forgot that check, thanks and thanks everyone else, all your answers helped!

Comment: You don't make it2 go ahead neither. Is that ok?

Answer (score 3):

My guess:

`L2` is empty, so `L2.begin()` is the same as `L2.end()`.

Which means `L2.begin()` is returning a non-referencable iterator and you are thus invoking undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

This (implementation specific) message suggests to me that you dereferenced an invalid iterator. This has nothing to do with syntax/compile-time semantics so no surprise that your compiler didn't complain. However note that iterators do have run-time semantics: in this case I'd wager that the code is called with an empty `L2` list, so that `itr2 == L2.end()`. That means that `*itr2` results in undefined behaviour. Luckily this seems to trigger an error-message rather than blowup in your face.

Answer (score 0):

A standard list iterator can be dereferenced as long as it's within the range of your list, i.e., [ list.begin(), list.end() ) while your list is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct that a bad list iterator is being dereferenced because of two bugs.  Looking at your pastebin,

This condition is backwards:

```
if ( (*itr1 == *itr2) && (itr2 != L2.end()) ) {
```

It should be

```
if ( (itr2 != L2.end()) && (*itr1 == *itr2) ) {
```

in order to check that itr2 is valid before using it.  Also, the first condition

```
if ( L1.empty() && L2.empty() ) {
            cout << "Returning an empty list because the two arugment lists were empty\n\n";
```

should be a disjunction:

```
if ( L1.empty() || L2.empty() ) {
            cout << "Returning an empty list because at least one of the two argument lists was empty\n\n";
```

but it's not even really necessary.

(Oh, and, are you aware of [set_intersection](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set_intersection.html), which is part of the standard library?)